# XCode Using two targets and Class Duplication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I am having a few problem with application white Labelling.

I have two targets App1, App2,
I have three Frameworks, CoreCustomFramework, App1Assets, App2Assets

And i have two class, Class1, and Class2, 2 is a clone of one with some imports that are only in App2Assets.

Class1 and Class2 share the same name, (Shouldnt matter as both are private to the AppFrameworks, rather then the coreFramework).

Now, App1 compiles fine, but App2 fails, and only on about 4 of 12 classes which are duplicated. Due to 'Duplicate interface definition for class...'.

```
In file included from /Users/ME/Dev/ProjectFolder/Modules/App2Assets/Classes/Table/TableViewController.m:

In file included from /Users/ME/Dev/ProjectFolder/Modules/CoreCustomFramework/Classes/Table/TableViewController+Private.h:9:

In file included from /Users/ME/Dev/ProjectFolder/Modules/App1Assets/Classes/Table/TableViewController.h:11:
```

Now some of the other Classes which are duplicated are fine. So im not sure why, the only thing i can think of is the PrivateHeaders setting is scanning the project folder So i should try and scan only the required modules folders. So core & specific app assets?

Answers on a postcard please.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you should check if class1 is also compiled with the target 2.

select its .m file in project navigator, open utility and show file inspector, then control its target membership: it should be just in target1...

Comment: Its Target Membership is purely App1, the header is currently set to project but i have tried setting both Class1 and Class2 headers to private, also the location currently relative to group, but have tried relative to project and absolute path. Both can still compile each other.

Comment: ...and i guess you already tried a "clean" and preferences:locations:derived data:  delete that folder...

Comment: Actually one thing i was thinking was doing a class extension, so Class1+privateApp2Version, adding that to the coreFramework and then when App1 compiles it might ignore that class as it isnt visable? not sure my OO skills arent as good as they should be.